# Creating a heatmap where image is changed in group of similar images

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, malware

Recently, I've been working on malware images. I have a group of gray-scale images which are from same malware family. I want to produce a heat map on image where images are being changed. How can we generate them?

Let's say **Part1**: I have a set of 2 images, I need to highlight the image parts which are being changed.

**Part2**: I have a group of images, I need a heat-map where most of the image parts are being changed.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm new to these image recognition things. So, I needed some suggestions or pathway from where to start these things.

Comment: :sighs: Okay then. Open two images and create a blank one the same size. Compare them pixel by pixel. If the same, copy. If different, paint a solid colour. simples. Use set of images to 'vote' for each altered pixel. Tally votes, divide by number of inputs - et voilla! (This is the trivial bit. Making a malware detect the presence of a debugger and subsequently alter its behaviour is far more fun)

Comment: How can we add density to it?

Comment: That's what the voting step does. Every pixel changed in every image will vote for a pixel coordinate. Divide by number of images and voila! a number - use this number to index into a pallete. Pallette selection is a whole other topic.

Comment: One more thing, I forgot to add. My bad!
Here the size of the images vary. (Basically, I converted the malware binary to images, depending on size of binary image- height and width are calculated). Can I use any Deep Learning technique to obtain which parts are same and which parts are different?

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you understand the way binaries are constructed, from a machine-language point of view? Changing an instruction that appears early-on in the binary can have the affect of changing most of the rest of the 'image' even though the program has only had a single instruction added or altered. Your proposed method seems unnecessarily complicated, given the small amount of info it can provide. That said, I'm a little rusty in the art - isn't diffing the binaries or comparing dissasembled listings going to give you a far more precise view of the changing behaviours?